# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre estas dos declaraciones?

Tags: java

hay alguna diferencia entre declarar el valor de un indice en el array de esta forma :

```
MatrizDinamica[j][i] = contador;
```

que de esta otra manera:

```
contador = MatrizDinamica[j][i];
```

esque mi principal duda es que al hacer este codigo , que es de una Matriz:

```
package Aborto;

public class Aborto5{

public static void main (String args[]){

int filas = 3, columnas = 3, contador = 1;

int MatrizDinamica[][] = new int  [filas][columnas];

for ( int j = 0; j < filas; j++ ){

for ( int i = 0; i < columnas; i++){

//***ESTA ES LA PARTE EN DONDE TENGO DUDA***

MatrizDinamica[j][i] = contador;        

System.out.print("[" + MatrizDinamica[j][i] + "]");
contador++;        
}

 System.out.println("");
 }
}

}
```

Ven como es este ejemplo el codigo de la declaración , o bien , donde se aguarda la variable "contador" en la matriz es la sig:

```
MatrizDinamica[j][i] = contador;
```

y esto me da como resultado lo siguiente:

```
[1][2][3]
[4][5][6]
[7][8][9]
```

pero si en el codigo cambio la misma declaración por el de esta forma:

```
contador = MatrizDinamica[j][i];
```

me sale en la consola el siguiente resultado:

```
[0][0][0]
[0][0][0]
[0][0][0]
```

por eso quiero saber ¿por que funcionan de diferente manera :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para aclarar, esta línea:

```
MatrizDinamica[j][i] = contador;
```

**NO ES LO MISMO QUE:**

```
contador = MatrizDinamica[j][i];
```

Ambas son asignaciones, pero la asignaciones se las hace a distintas variables. La primera asignas el valor de la variable *contador*(que comienza en 1, luego 2, 3,...) a la posición indicada... En cambio tu segundo caso es al revés y de hecho si lo harías no tendrías ningún error de código, pero no habría lógica al hacerlo... Lo que haces es asignarle a contador lo que hay en esa posición(y como no les diste un valor a cada posición es que siempre tienen 0)... Y el error de la lógica es que siempre incrementas *contador*, pero aún así no importa porque siempre cambias su valor al asignarle una y otra vez un 0

Tu código de ejemplo hace exactamente lo que te ha devuelto(te llena cada posición con números sucesivos del 1 al 9)

Pero el segundo caso siempre te va dar 0 porque nunca hiciste asignaciones a cada posición...

*No confundas la asignación de variables con una igualdad aritmética. Se usa el mismo signo pero tienen distinto objetivo*...

Answer (score 3):

Cuando usas `MatrizDinamica[j][i] = contador;` lo que estas haciendo es tomar el valor guardado en la variable `contador` (el cual es 1) para guardarlo en la [j][i] celda de la matriz y luego con `contador++;` aumentas el valor guardado en `contador`.

Cuando usas `contador = MatrizDinamica[j][i];` lo que haces es tomar el valor guardado en la [j][i] celda de la matriz (el cual es 0) y lo asignas a la variable `contador` y aunque aumentes la cantidad con `contador++;` luego lo reasignas a 0.

Answer (score 0):

Es la manera en que estas asignando las variables en la primera opción estas recorriendo la matriz y en cada una de las casillas estas agregando el valor de contador.

En la segunda opción estas asignando el valor del recorrido de las matrices a la variable contador.

Nota: Recuerda que java te llena los valores por default en 0

por ello se muestra 0 ya que en ningún momento cambiaste el valor de la matriz